# Suggestions for coding an ContextMenu with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to code a contextmenu directive for my project. First of all created a sample context menu as an angular JS directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive("myContextMenu", function(){
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: true,
  template: "",
  link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
    elem.bind "contextmenu", ->
      scope.$apply ->
        console.log "Right click to an item."
    elem.bind "mouseleave", ->
    elem.bind 'mouseover', ->
      elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

Here is my sample HTML file:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div my-context-menu>
    Right click to display a context-menu
  </div>
</div>
```

When I right click to the text, I want to append some div(for ex. Sample Context Menu). When the mouse leaves the div I want the Sample Context Menu to be removed.

What is the right approach for that. Should I fill the "template" field of the directive? Should I hide and show the context menu? Or should I add and remove the context menu?

Any kind of help is kindly appreciated?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this project  https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-context-menu

In my opinion the important thing is how you define the context menu and good example to think about it is ng-repeat (this way you will have to think about scope a bit more)

I think that defining menu inline would be quite clean

i.e

```
<my-context-menu>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a ng-click="f()">Option 1</a>
      </li>
     <li>
        <a ng-click="f()">Option 2</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</my-context-menu>
```

this way directive would be concerned only how the menu is displayed and the content would be defined inline and you could easily call function in current scope

I find showing / hiding div would good enough - maybe when u have huge number of items in page and different context menus creating div on the fly would be more suitable

Answer (score -1):

I would use a more generic approach and make reusable to various controllers. Think about configurable option for adding items to menus. What methods would be called by clicking that item - make this also customizable.

Also the positioning of context menu, if menu oepned at right corner and gets hidden within window - have detection at place to shift the menu to left.

You can check the one I have written - https://github.com/shekhardesigner/Context-Menu-Angular-Directive